# PowerApps and Connecting to SharePoint in Canvas

Tags: canvas, sharepoint, microsoft-teams, powerapps

I am trying to connect to a table of an excel in a sharepoint in canas powerapps, however when I copy the link or try to look for it, it does not bring the list of documents I want to see and instead shows me the only two folder from Teams. I have been following the steps in the Docs but still same result

Is there any step before this I would need to follow ? Thanks in Advance [image]

Comment: Could you please share the documentation which you are following so that we can also check it from our end.

Comment: Hi @ChetanSharma-msft unfortunately I wont be able to share the exact doc. but This is happening for a few excel files I have (its already formatted as Table) Please kindly see my other question in regards to powerapp, I tried various ways but it looks like the system cannot read my tables

Answer (score 2):

Try as following:

1.Add new data source and select Excel Online data source:

[image]

2.Then select the SharePoint site as location, find the table as shown below:

[image]
3.The table in SharePoint library excel file has been added as shown below:

[image]

More information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-excel

Comment: Thank you @Julie_MSFT I have also tried the following and then it will lead me to the following Problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69444900/powerapp-form-function-keeps-the-data-source-correctly-but-doesnt-read-it   , Where although I have formatted my excel as table the form does not read my excel file

Comment: Do you try other excel files within table to compare the result?

Comment: Yes I have, one thing I also tried, was to create a table from scratch and pull that one in, which it brings it in but it doesn't read it in the form as the figure in the other post

Comment: Do other users occur the same issue in your tenant?

Comment: I am the only user on this app at the moment

Comment: I mean, can other users link the tables in the sharepoint excel file in your tenant's Power Apps?

Comment: HI @ChetanSharma-msft, I used a different approach and it worked, the issue i had here did not work no matter how many times I tried. The form in powerapp does not read the table (although it does recognize there is one) I have used the Sharepoint list function and brought the Form parameters from the sharepoint list instead.

Comment: @Julie_MSFT Thanks for your solution, I tried this one and it didnt work as commented above. I used Sharepoint List instead